# Blank page displayed in php CodeIgniter

Tags: php

I am facing a very strange problem . Please help me.

I am using CodeIgniter framework. When i run the php code in browser then instead of showing views it displays nothing and when i echo any thing else in my controller then then it gets echoed.

when i see the source code by right clicking on page in Mozilla browser whloe source code is there but when i use the firebug to see the code the all code is there except body tag is blank.

**FireBug Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>temp</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/dawn/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/dawn/assets/css/custom.css">
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Controller:  home.php**

```
<?php   
            defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
            class Home extends MY_Controller
            {
            public function index()
            {
            $this->load->view('home');
            }
            }
?>
```

View: home.php

```
            <?php 
            echo require_once('header.php');


            ?>
            <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-6 bg-1">
            <?php echo anchr('student/index', '<h1>Student</h1>'); ?>
            <?php 
            $image_properties = array(
            'src'   => 'assets/img/sun.jpg',
            'alt'   => 'Logo',
            'class' => 'img-circle',
            'width' => '150',
            'height'=> '150',
            'title' => ' ',
            'rel'   => ''
            );
            echo img($image_properties);
            ?>
            <h3>Fulfill Your Dreams of Education in Abroad.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-6 bg-1">
            <a  href="#">
            <h1>Institution</h1>
            <?php 
            $image_properties = array(
            'src'   => 'assets/img/sun.jpg',
            'alt'   => 'Logo',
            'class' => 'img-circle',
            'width' => '150',
            'height'=> '150',
            'title' => ' ',
            'rel'   => ''
            );
            echo img($image_properties);
            ?>
            <h3>Fulfill Your Dreams of Education in Abroad.</h3>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-6 bg-1">
            <a  href="#">
            <h1>Fun Buddies</h1>
            <?php 
            $image_properties = array(
            'src'   => 'assets/img/sun.jpg',
            'alt'   => 'Logo',
            'class' => 'img-circle',
            'width' => '150',
            'height'=> '150',
            'title' => ' ',
            'rel'   => ''
            );
            echo img($image_properties);
            ?>
            <h3>Fulfill Your Dreams of Education in Abroad.</h3>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid text-center col-sm-6 bg-1">
            <a  href="#">
            <h1>Counselling</h1>
            <?php 
            $image_properties = array(
            'src'   => 'assets/img/sun.jpg',
            'alt'   => 'Logo',
            'class' => 'img-circle',
            'width' => '150',
            'height'=> '150',
            'title' => ' ',
            'rel'   => ''
            );
            echo img($image_properties);
            ?>
            <h3>Fulfill Your Dreams of Education in Abroad.</h3>
            </a>
            </div>  

            <?php echo include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: On each `.php` page after starting `<?php` write `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check for possible error

Comment: check application/logs folder if no file generated for the day please enable error logging in config.php i.e. $config['log_threshold'] = 1;

Comment: what is your folder structure?

Comment: just do one thing first ... go to home.php view file and remove all php code and just type static text and check whether its working or not. if it works then there must be some problem in your view file php code.

Comment: and why you are including your **echo require_once('header.php');** in **home.php view file** .. you are using CodeIgniter and it has rules and structure to follow dear. have a look CI documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: Thanks all i was little busy so count reply....Thanks for your reply.